# Which is correct formula for Plot/Gibbs distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Helllo all, I am using Bayesian rule to classification the data. It has two term: likelihood and prior terms. The prior term can estimate by Gibbs distribution. According to the [MRF-GRF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fy5gnrcjzhv92tw/MRF.pdf?dl=0) (page 12),[book](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9781848002784) equivalence described by Hammersley-Clifford theorem (known as Plot model), the Gibbs potential value is defined as: 
$$V_c(x_i) =
\begin{cases}
\beta,  & \text{if $x_i, x_j$ same class, $x_j$ is neighbor of $x_i$} \\
-\beta, & \text{if $x_i \not=x_j$ }
\end{cases}$$
where $\beta$ is positive.

However, I found other [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885606001223) (page 4) give the other fomular as

$$V_c(x_i) =
\begin{cases}
-\beta,  & \text{if $x_i, x_j$ same class, $x_j$ is neighbor of $x_i$} \\
\beta, & \text{if $x_i \not=x_j$ }
\end{cases}$$

My question is that which one is correct formula? I think second one is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, both are correct, as they are modeling different phenomena. Note that for *any* finite set $\Omega$ and *any* function $U: \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\forall\omega\in\Omega, \ e^{-U(\omega)}>0$; consequently, these quantities *always* provide a valid discrete probability distribution on $\Omega$:
$$p(\omega) = \frac{e^{-U(\omega)}}{\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}e^{-U(\omega)}} > 0,\quad \sum_{\omega\in\Omega} p(\omega)=1.
$$

In each of the articles you cite, a prior distribution is modeled in just this way, using
$$U(\omega) = \sum_{C\in\mathcal{C}}V_C(\omega)
$$ 
where $V_C(\omega)$ is a "potential" and $\mathcal{C}$ is a finite set. These potential functions are supposed to be selected to make the prior distribution reflect whatever information is assumed to be known *a priori* about the system being modeled, which of course may vary greatly from case to case.

(By the way, I used [this link](https://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~kato/papers/ivc2001.pdf) for the paper by Kato & Pong, since yours was behind a pay-wall.)

Comment: Thank r.e.s. I used both way to model prior information in image. However, they gave different result. With first way, the piror information will decrease when its neighbor labels are same (it looks wrong). While, second way shown that prior information/ probablity belongs the a class increases, if its neighbor labels are same. It looks make sence. I think Kato paper looks right formula in segmentation